# why doesn't ach work on weekends or holidays?

Tags: payment, payment-processing, banking

It seems strange to me that ACH payments can only be made on business days, during business hours. SFTP, SSH, HTTP, etc.. no other protocol has a "works only on business days" limitation like ACH does. My question is...  why? Why can ACH payments only be processed during working hours?

I can't imagine a person is needed to manually sign off on each one before it happens. There'd be too much volume for that I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

SFTP, SSH, HTTP, etc., are all computer communications protocols.

ACH is a banking protocol, made for interacting with banks and for moving people's money around.  Banks (and other financial institutions) get to say when they open and close, and when they are available for business.

ACH protocol transactions are business transactions and so are subject to extra rules, regulations, and oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this:

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/about_ach_payments.htm

I believe it is down to no one being around to approve the payment...